# How to give a big O estimate/visualize for these while loop?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics, computer-science, computational-complexity

This is from Discrete Mathematics and its applications

[image]

[image]

I am currently working on problem 4.
 I was able to see that for problem 2, that one operation one will run n times for every n(meaning in total, the operation will run n^2 times or the big O estimate would be O(n^2)). Is there a similar pattern to problem 4?

Answer (score 1):

Each time the loop executes, $i$ is doubled. So if the loop executes $M$ times then $i$ will be $2^M$. But the loop halts when $i > n$. So how big is $M$ when the loop terminates, compared to $n$?

Comment: when 2^M > n? meaning if you take log of both sides M > log2(n) ? How would you know the exact value of M?

Comment: You basically answered your own question. =) You don't need to know the exact value of $M$. Just that it is $O(\log_2 n)$.

Comment: oh because it will run log2n times so it will be bounded by O(log2n) just like running n^2 times will be bounded by O(n^2)

Comment: Yes, exactly. Technically you should show that $\Omega(\log_2 n)$ is a lower bound probably also, but that is fairly obvious.

Comment: doesn't the question just ask for big oh though?